# Show a form in a modal instead of a page PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have a function called `form_print` that displays my form, like this :

```
$form = array() ;
$form['name'] = "post"; 
$form['action'] = url()."admin/page/index" ; 
$form['method'] = "post";
$form['type'] = "multipart";
$form['items'] = array (
    array ("type"=>"hidden", "name"=>"action", "value"=>"insert"),  
    array ("type"=>"hidden", "name"=>"language", "value"=>"FR"), 
    array (
            "type"=>"textbox", 
            "label"=>"Title", 
            "name"=>"title", 
            "properties"=> array(
                "required" => true
            )
        ), 
    array (
            "type"=>"TinyMCE", 
            "label"=>"Content", 
            "name"=>"body", 
            "properties"=> array(
                "required" => true, 
                "class" => "tinymce", 
            )
        ),
    array ("type"=>"file", "label"=>"Image", "name"=>"image", 
                "properties" => array (
                    "value"=>"", 
                    "view" => "thumbs" ,
                    "extensions" => "jpg,jpeg,gif,png" 
                ), 
            ), 
    array ("type"=>"Button", "name"=>"submit", "label"=>"Submit"), 

    ) ; 
    form_print($form) ;
```

[image: two muppets]
And it works fine, but I was wondering if I could display it in a modal. Any way I can achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: I can think of a couple ways to implement this. 1) you could have the form hidden and use the hidden div for the content of the modal. 2) You could have the HTML returned via AJAX and load this into the modal. What are you using for your modal? jQuery UI Dialog?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is wrap the form in an absolutely-positioned DIV and use `display:none` until you need to display it.

Answer (score 0):

I developed something similar for a client a little while ago, it was a ticketing system that needed to pop out instead of leading the user to another page. I successfully did this using a inline modal. If your unsure what this is checkout the fancybox version. Its really easyto use.

http://fancybox.net

Good luck.